# Calling a void function to another void function BEFORE calling to the main function

Tags: c++, function, void

Please bear with me as I am brand new to coding.

I am trying to figure out how to call a void function to another void function. Here is what I came up with:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void test(int x,int n, double &test1);
void ref(int a,int b, double &ref1);

int main()
{
    int x,n;
    double test1;
    cout<<"Enter x and n: ";
    cin>>x>>n;
    
    test(x,n,test1);

    cout<<"Your value is "<<test1;
    return 0;
}

void test(int x,int n, double &test1)
{
    int a, b,ref1;
    ref(a,b,ref1);
    test1=x+n + ref1;
}
    
void ref(int a,int b, double &ref1)
{
    ref1=a+b;
}
```

But I am getting an error:

```
main.cpp: In function 'void test(int, int, double&)':
main.cpp:32:17: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'double&' to an rvalue of type 'double'
   32 |         ref(a,b,ref1);
      |                 ^~~~
main.cpp:14:31: note:   initializing argument 3 of 'void ref(int, int, double&)'
   14 | void ref(int a,int b, double &ref1);
      |                       ~~~~~~~~^~~~
```

I am trying to use the `void ref` function inside the `void test` function and print out under the `main` function.  Can I do this?

Comment: The error message (which you should be putting as text into the question, not into an image, see [ask]) is not particularly clear about the issue, but just look at the type of `ref1` in `test` and in `ref`. I think you should notice something wrong there...

Comment: Mechanically, yes, the `test` function can call the `ref` function, if the arguments match the signatures.  But it is a mistake to use variables `a` and `b` after failing to initialize them.

Comment: Also, what do you expect the value of `a` and `b` in `ref` to be if you pass uninitialized `a` and `b` from `test` to them?

Comment: And, except if you are trying to practice references, there is no reason to write the results to reference out-parameters. You can just return the results of your calculations from the functions instead (after replacing `void` by the correct return type) and assign the return values to the corresponding variable in the caller. That's much more natural.

Comment: The fact that these functions return no results (are declared `void`) is not material to the problem. You need the provided arguments to match the declared parameters in type.

Comment: The error message does not match the source code you showed us. When I compile your code, I get messages about lines 24 and 6; you show messages about lines 32 and 14. I get an error message "error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘double&’ to a value of type ‘**int**’"; you show "error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'double&' to an rvalue of type '**double**'" (emphasis added). It is not useful to show us error messages for a different piece of source code. Compile your code, then copy-and-paste both the code and the messages into your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ref()` function takes a non-const reference to a `double` in its 3rd parameter.  However, your `test()` function is initializing that parameter with an `int` variable.  So, the compiler has to perform an implicit conversion from `int` to a temporary `double`, but then fails because a non-const reference can't bind to a temporary object, hence the compiler error.

You need to change `test()` to pass a `double` variable to `ref()` (just like `main()` is doing when calling `test()`), eg:

```
void test(int x,int n, double &test1)
{
    int a, b;
    double ref1; // <-- here
    ref(a,b,ref1);
    test1=x+n + ref1;
}
```

Also note that `test()` is not initializing its `a` or `b` variables with any values, but is still passing them to `ref()`, which will then sum their values together and assign the result to `ref1`.  That summation will have *undefined behavior*, and the resulting value of `ref1` will be *indeterminate*.  You need to fix that, too.